# Set File path using javascript

Tags: html, codeigniter, csv

How can i set a **default file path** in **HTML** using javascript? If it is possible , if not please advice me another thing to make it.

Everytime i will export the CSV file ***it will save and replace the old CSV file in the same path were i can get my old CSV file***. Thank you in advance for the help. I have no idea how can i do it. By the way i am using codeigniter here.

i tried this code but it didn't work

```
$(document).ready(function () {

                function exportTableToCSV($table, filename) {

                    var $rows = $table.find('tr:has(td)'),
                        tmpColDelim = String.fromCharCode(11), 
                        tmpRowDelim = String.fromCharCode(0), 


                        colDelim = '","',
                        rowDelim = '"\r\n"',

                        csv = '"' + $rows.map(function (i, row) {
                            var $row = $(row),
                                $cols = $row.find('td');

                            return $cols.map(function (j, col) {
                                var $col = $(col),
                                    text = $col.text();

                                return text.replace('"', '""'); 

                            }).get().join(tmpColDelim);

                        }).get().join(tmpRowDelim)
                            .split(tmpRowDelim).join(rowDelim)
                            .split(tmpColDelim).join(colDelim) + '"',

                        csvData = 'data:application/csv;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(csv);

                    $(this)
                        .attr({
                        'download': filename,
                            'href': csvData,
                            'target': 'C:\xampp\htdocs\Datacast\bin\pdw_table.csv'
                    });
                }
                $(".export").on('click', function (event) {

                });
            });
```

it cause me error at the **target**

Answer (score 2):

> How can i set a default file path in HTML using javascript?

You can't.

> If it is possible , if not please advice me another thing to make it.

Write a stand-alone application that isn't subject to the browser sandbox and use it instead of a web browser.